# Problem in fomating date, when using date function with strtotime function 

Tags: php

I am using date function along with strtotime function to format the date.

Ex:

```
<?php
$input_date = '03-JUL-09 14:53';

$formatted_date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($input_date));

echo $formatted_date;
?>
```

Gives me a expected output: **2009-07-03 14:53:00**

while if the input is changed to(I am removing the minute part)-

```
<?php
$input_date = '03-JUL-09 14';

$formatted_date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($input_date));

echo $formatted_date;
?>
```

The output here is **1970-01-01 05:30:00**, which is not at all expected.

Whats the mistake I am doing and how it can be fixed.

Thanks

Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it comes down to the inability of strtotime() to determine which numbers are what in your 2nd date string.

My best advice is to normalize your date-time value before passing it to strtotime().  Something simple like this might be enough

```
if ( false === strpos( $input_date, ':' ) )
{
  $input_date .= ':00';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1970-01-01 05:30:00** is the time in India at the Unix epoch (**1970-01-01 00:00:00** GMT/UTC). This means that `strtotime` returned either `0`, or `false`, which was converted to `0` by `date`. This is because it could not process its input, as others have explained.

Answer (score 2):

The function strtotime expects to be given a string containing a US English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.
You can use strings like

- 03 july 2009
- now
- 09-07-03
- 09-07-03 14:00:00
- +1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds
- last Monday

But not incomplete date format like "09-07-03 14". The parser don't understand it and returns nothing so when you call `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($input_date));` it returns the 0 timestamp (January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), cause it's the default value.

You have to give a right string that can be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

03-JUL-09 14 does not seem to be a valid date string, 03-JUL-09 14:00 works fine

from the php manual: strtotime — Parse **about** any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

`1970-01-01` is a typical baseline date (in `ctime` for example).  I believe the output is formatting a value of `0` into a date, thus the `1970`, and the unrelated `05:30:00` time of day.

I believe this is a fluke in attempting to format a date that does not include all the requested time elements.  Can you pad the date data to generate a complete input date?

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` fails to parse the second string when you remove the minute part. It doesn't know what the extra "14" means so it returns `bool(false)`. Calling `date(false)` returns the same thing as `date(0)`, i.e. it gives you the date of the UNIX epoch: January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT adjusted for your local timezone.